# How can I limit database query time during web requests?

Tags: django, performance, postgresql

We've got a pretty typical django app running on postgresql 9.0. We've recently discovered some db queries that have run for over 4 hours, due to inefficient searches in the admin interface. While we plan to fix these queries, as a safeguard we'd like to artificially constrain database query time to 15 seconds--but only in the context of a web request; batch jobs and celery tasks should not be bounded by this constraint.

How can we do that? Or is it a terrible idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to set up a role/user that is only used to run the web requests, then set the statement_timeout on that role.

```
ALTER ROLE role_name SET statement_timeout = 15000
```

All other roles will use the global setting of statement_timeout (which is disabled in a stock install).

Comment: + 1 Good option. Just remember the user can reset this for their session by issuing the same command with a higher timeout. With a web call I assume this wouldn't be an issue however as the user won't have an interface to set it.

Comment: Matthew Wood: Wow, what a great suggestion. Thank you. StarShip3000: This answer solves the technical problem, which is all I care about. The issue you raise is not a technology problem, it's an HR problem. Those are easy to solve.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you for that. You can also issue `set  session statement_timeout = 15000;` if you only want to limit a specific session, or even `set local statement_timeout = 15000;`. More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-STATEMENT-TIMEOUT

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle this manually. That is checking for the 15 second rule and killing the queries that violate it.

Query pg_stat_activity and find the violators and issue calls to pg_terminate_backend(procpid) to kill the offenders.

Something like this in a loop:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.procpid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'TARGET_DB'
  AND usename = 'WEBUSERNAME'
  AND (now()-query_start) > '00:00:15';
```

Comment: This of course assumes you know the names of the accounts the web interface uses.  Though if you have a list of ip addresses from your webserver box you could use those as well. Check out the pg_stat_activity table.

Answer (score -4):

As far as the timing goes, you could pass all of your queries through a class which, on instantiation, spawns two threads: one for the query, and one for a timer. If the timer reaches 15 seconds, then kill the thread with the query.

As far as figuring out if the query is instantiated from a web request, I don't know enough about Django to be able to help you. Simplistically, I would say, in your class that handles your database calls, an optional parameter to the constructor could be something like `context`, which could be `http` in the event of a web request and `""` for anything else.

Comment: This is a very over-engineered solution to the problem with tons of potential pitfalls, and doing work which the database system an handle natively.